# Round number off to 2sf in list

Tags: python

I am very new to python, I have a set of data in a list that will output the follow:

```
[(['S1'], 123.6, 4, -3.09710082168993), (['S2'], 189.6, 4, -3.09710082168993)]
[(['S1'], 123.6, 4, -1974.1075190129), (['S2'], 189.6, 4, -1974.1075190129)]
```

I get this output by these code:

```
plateX = g_o.getresults(phase, g_o.ResultTypes.NodeToNodeAnchor.X, 'node') 
plateY = g_o.getresults(phase, g_o.ResultTypes.NodeToNodeAnchor.Y, 'node') 
plateM = g_o.getresults(phase, g_o.ResultTypes.NodeToNodeAnchor.AnchorForce2D, 'node')
layer = (
['S1'],
['S2'],    
['S3'],
['S4'],
['S5'],
['S6'],)

result = zip(layer, plateX, plateY, plateM)
test1 = list(result)
print(test1)
```

How should I round off the result but keep the "S1" , "S2" as the indicator of the result?

Thanks for the help.

```
E.g.
[(['S1'], 123.6, 4, -3.09710082168993), (['S2'], 189.6, 4, -3.09710082168993)]
to
[(['S1'], 123.6, 4, -3.1), (['S2'], 189.6, 4, -3.1)]
```

That is what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: did you try `round(number, precision)` or `ceil()`?

Comment: Also, have you explored dictionaries? This data looks like it wants to be in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how should i add "round(number, precision)" command into the list as the list is combine with "text,value,value", sorry that im very new and complete stupid to python code. @Vj

Comment: @Ramkishore M , what do you mean by that...?

Comment: @KLo, dictionary is another data structure in Python. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the tuple to a list and then round the element.

```
d = [(['S1'], 123.6, 4, -3.09710082168993), (['S2'], 189.6, 4, -3.09710082168993)]
d = list(map(list, d))              #Convert to list.
for i in d:
    i[-1] = round(i[-1], 2)      #round value.
d = list(map(tuple, d))             #Convert to tuple.
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
[(['S1'], 123.6, 4, -3.1), (['S2'], 189.6, 4, -3.1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, however after i map the list it print the result of "<map object at 0x00000000032E85F8>" instead of a proper value, what should i do? @Rakesh

Comment: Updated snippet for python3

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line :

```
result = zip(layer, plateX, plateY, round(plateM, 2))
```

You can use the round function, which takes as first argument the number and the second argument is the precision.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have tried that and i have got the error of: 
    
result = zip(layer, plateX, plateY, round(plateM,2) )
    TypeError: type PlxProxyObjectValues doesn't define __round__ method

Comment: You cannot round the entire set of values together

Comment: @KLo this might work plz convert plateM to float than try float(plateM)

Answer (score 0):

You can round them in place using generator

```
result = zip(layer, plateX, plateY, (round(x, 2) for x in plateM))
```

Saves memory and work for interpreter

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how about if i want to round plateX, plateY and plateM all together into 2sf are there any cleaner way..? thanks again @Ramkishore M

Comment: do the same generator for plateX and plateY too